# Remove Content-Type header in apache

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, content-type

How to remove header content-type in apache ?

The following code does not work

`header_remove('content-type');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
header("content-type: none");
```

I don't know why, but it's worked for me.

I cannot find any reference mentioned about this. but it's simply removed the `content-type` from header for me. It' may be apache's bug or PHP's bug. So try it and use it with careful.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:');
```

This completely removed the `Content-Type` header from the response. Like you, using `header_remove()` didn't do a thing and [Hereblur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326817/remove-content-type-header-in-apache/18326865#18326865) left me with `Content-Type: none` in the response.

Comment: Doesn't work, header still stubbornly gets sent. What's your setup?

Comment: PHP 5.5.14, Apache 2.4.9, Drupal 7.34 — What's your setup? If you're using a framework of some sort it may be trying to be smart about setting the headers.

Comment: I'm not on a framework. I've got a fresh PHP installation (Win 8.1) and am running the [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (no Apache).

Comment: Unfortunately, all I know about this is written in my answer. I would suggest posting a new question specific to PHP and the its built-in web server.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what php.ini directives you have, and what PHP you use (CLI, CGI, ...).

This answer is based on PHP 5.4, running in CGI.

Note in php.ini:

```
default_mimetype = text/html
```

That's the default value, that PHP sends as:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

If you want to get rid of it, you have to remove the default value by creating the header again, then you can remove the header:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header_remove('Content-Type');
```